# Telnet check in bash script

Tags: shell-script, solaris, telnet

I want to run the following commands in bash script form in Solaris 10:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
debug
quit
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Do you have expect installed, either as a binary or as a Perl module?

Comment: I want write this with builtin packages and modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any luck with having bash configured with `--enable-net-redirections`, [Bash's special redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) might be useful:

```
cat <<EOF >/dev/tcp/localhost/25
debug
quit
EOF
```

When you're also interested in the output from the server:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/25 # open localhost:25 as fd 3
cat <<EOF >&3 # write to fd 3
debug
quit
EOF
cat <&3   # read from fd 3
exec >&3- # close fd 3
```

Comment: # cat u > /dev/tcp/localhost/25
/dev/tcp/localhost/25: cannot create

Comment: @Archemar It seems not all the distro/system come with the bash with this feature enabled.  I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as per sugested, and after testing, this work on linux, but not on solaris as OP request.

pipe style

```
(echo debug ; echo qui ) | nc localhost 25
```

or (heredoc style)

```
nc localhost 25 <<EOF
debug
quit
EOF
```

on my ubuntu, telnet do not take input, while netcat does.

Comment: It may be better to use `netcat` (sometimes also available as `nc` as that waits for the remote connection to close before quitting; piping into telnet may cause telnet to stop before the remote has had a chance to react.

Comment: nc command not found. This is same for netcat.